# P: TDA y PUNTEROS en c

Tags: c

Alguien sabe como puedo solucionar este "error", lo que necesito hacer es acceder a la variable puntaje pero tengo que acceder a cartonJugador primero algo asi ---> ***j->cartonJugador[0].puntaje*** pero por algo motivo me tira error cuando hago eso o ***j->cartonJugador[0]->puntaje*** tampco me funciona.
¿Alguien tiene alguna solución para este problema que tengo?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct Carton{

    int puntaje;
};
typedef struct Carton *cartones;

struct Jugador {

    cartones cartonJugador[3];


};
typedef struct Jugador *jugadores;

int main()
{


    return 0;
}

void prueba(cartones c){

jugadores j;

j->cartonJugador[0].puntaje; // acá
j->cartonJugador[0]->puntaje; //y acá

}
```

Comment: Ya te dieron una respuesta, sin embargo, no uses `typedef` para esconder los punteros, es una mala practica. Cualquier persona que use tu codigo se confundira..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cartonJugador` es un arreglo de apuntadores así que primero tienes que indicar cual cartonJugador estas tratando de usar para luego ir con la flecha.... y si no me equivoco, dado que estas usando apuntadores, vas a tener que reservar memoria para poder usarlos (usar `malloc`, `calloc` y tal). Sacando el tema de reservar la memoria del problema, la forma de utilizarlo seria:

```
j->cartonJugador[0]->puntaje // el índice puede ir de 0 a 2
```